# moving text with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm trying to convert some guys tutorial from an animation that moves when the mouse moves to moving when scrolling down. it is moving now but only when I move both my mouse and scroll at the same time.

I am looking for a method that moves the words when just scrolling

```
<section id="bbbb">
<div class="text">
<h2 style="--i:0.5"><span> because boring is bad for business</span>
</h2></div> 
</section>

const position = document.documentElement;
position.addEventListener('mousewheel', e => {
position.style.setProperty('--x', e.clientX + 'px')
```

})

```
.text h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: calc(var(--x)) 100px 0 rgba(255, 255,255,0.2);
  transform: translateX(calc(0% - var(--x)*var(--i)));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

your javascript will be like this

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#container");

element.addEventListener('wheel', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  element.scrollBy({
    left: event.deltaY < 0 ? -30 : 30,
    
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y:hidden;
  max-width: 50rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.text h2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 6.5em;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-shadow: calc(var(--x)) 100px 0 rgba(255, 255,255,0.2);
  transform: translateX(calc(0% - var(--x)*var(--i)));
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <section id="bbbb">
    <div class="text">
      <h2 style="--i:0.5"><span> because boring is bad for business</span>
    </h2></div> 
  </section>
</div>
```